# String Split With Unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode

First off I been searching the web for this solution.

How to:

```
<''.split('');

> ['','','']
```

Simply express of what I'll like to do. But also with other Unicode characters like poo.

Comment: I'm a little confused. `''.split('');` appears to work for me: ["", "", ""]

Comment: I've read about the poo test before. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode has a good explanation. The key thing is  has a code point above U+FFFF and is encoded using 2 bytes with UTF-16.

Comment: If you want a function `''.split('');` to return`['', '']` you should edit your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in [***JavaScript has a Unicode problem***](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode), in ES6 you can do this quite easily by using the new `...` spread operator. This causes the string iterator (another new ES6 feature) to be used internally, and because that iterator is designed to deal with code points rather than UCS-2/UTF-16 code units, it works the way you want:

```
console.log([...'']);
// → ['', '']
```

Try it out here: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=console.log%28%0A%20%20%5B%2e%2e%2e%27%F0%9F%92%A9%F0%9F%92%A9%27%5D%0A%29%3B

A more generic solution:

```
function splitStringByCodePoint(string) {
  return [...string];
}

console.log(splitStringByCodePoint(''));
// → ['', '']
```

Comment: Great now all I have to do is wait for this to be standard across browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Isn't there a regexp to deal with situation like this?

Comment: @L2L2L You don’t, actually. Just write your code in ES6 and transpile it using Babel.js (which I linked to) before deploying it. That way it works even in ES5 environments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion everyone. Thanks for the responses @Mathias Bynens.

Answer (score 0):

for ...  of could loop through string contains unicode characters,

```
let string = ""
for(var c of string)
    console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions work well for simple emojis, but not for the one from an extended set and the ones that use [Surrogate Pairs](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2)

For example:

```
splitStringByCodePoint("❤️")
// Returns: [ "❤", "️" ]
```

To handle these cases properly you'll need a purpose-built library, like for example:

https://github.com/dotcypress/runes

https://github.com/essdot/spliddit