# ES2015 string iterator information about index

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, unicode

In ES2015 or ES6, strings are iterable.
This feature can be used to handle Unicode surrogate pairs properly.

For example,

```js
const str = "a\u{1F436}b";
for (const ch of str) {
    f(ch);
}
```

will call `f()` 3 times whereas

```js
const str = "a\u{1F436}b";
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    f(ch[i]);
}
```

will call `f()` 4 times.

What I want to do is getting the beginning or ending indices of those characters.
For example, for `str = "a\u{1F436}b"`, I want to get something like `[0, 1, 3]` because each unicode character starts at the index 0, 1, 3 respectively.

However, the iterator does not seem to give information about the index.

How can I get the indices?

Comment: Could you elaborate how these indexes are going to be used? I have a feeling this is a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: You can just accumulate the `ch.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about doing something like this

```js
var str = "a\u{1F436}b";

let current = 0
let indexes = [...str].map(a=> {
  let temp = current
  current += a.length
  return temp
})

console.log(indexes)
```

[`String Split With Unicode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990466/string-split-with-unicode)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a simple Unicode-aware regular expression with the [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) RegExp method in a loop:

```js
const str = "a\u{1F436}b";
const regex = /./gu;
let indexes = [ ];
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(str))
{
    // let ch = match[0];
    indexes.push(match.index);
}
console.log(indexes);
```